# Finding One-Sided Limits Algebraically by Breaking Functions into Piecewise Parts

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

I've found myself very reliant on graphs in the past for solving **one-sided limits**, but I'd prefer to **solve them algebraically**. [Without plugging in nearby values to the right and left of the value $a$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/917518/finding-one-sided-limits-algebraically-without-using-a-graph), where $\lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x)=L$, how would one go about doing this? As I've made evident in the title, the approach I'd like to take is to break apart the function into piecewise pieces at all discontinuities, so that I can approach the one-sided limit from both sides of each piecewise function. Here's an example:

$$f(x)={\sqrt{x^2-2x+1}\over{x-1}}\text{, }x\ne1$$
$$\lim\limits_{x \to 1}f(x)=\varnothing$$
$$g(x)=\begin{cases}1 & \text{if}\,\,\,x>1 \\ -1 & \text{if}\,\,\,x<1\end{cases}$$
$$\lim_\limits{x \to 1^+}f(x)=\lim_\limits{x \to 1} g_1(x)=1$$
$$\lim_\limits{x \to 1^-}f(x)=\lim_\limits{x \to 1} g_2(x)=-1$$

Where $g(x)_1$ is $g(x)$ where $x>1$, and $g(x)_2$ is $g(x)$ where $x<1$. In this case, it was easy to break up the function (at least based on graphical evidence) into piecewise parts.

Suppose we have a function $h(x)$ that's far messier than $f(x)$. **How would I break it apart into a piecewise function (without any graphical evidence), whose pieces are between the discontinuities in the function, such that if $a$, $b$, and $c$ are points at which $h(x)$ is discontinuous, then**

$$p(x)=\begin{cases}j(x) & \text{if}\,\,\,x<a \\ k(x) & \text{if}\,\,\,a<x<b \\ l(x) & \text{if}\,\,\,b<x<c \\ m(x) & \text{if}\,\,\,x>c\end{cases}$$

and so on and so forth? Again, the advantage I see in this is that you could get the limit at the desired point using the new functions that the piecewise function $p(x)$ contains like so:

$$\lim_\limits{x \to a^-}p(x)=\lim_\limits{x \to a}j(x)=L_-$$
$$\lim_\limits{x \to a^+}p(x)=\lim_\limits{x \to a}k(x)=L_+$$

---

**EDIT:** $a$, $b$, and $c$, as previously defined, could also just be any points at which you'd like to find a limit, regardless of whether or not there's a discontinuity there.

Here's an example of what I refer to as a messy function:

$$h(x)=2+\frac{\sqrt{x+5}}{x^2+2x-5}$$

---

**EDIT 2:** Below is an image that might help to illustrate the problem.

[Example of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4buKi.png)

$y_1$ and $y_2$ are points on the function $f\left(x\right)$, which are separated by a jump discontinuity. Suppose that $f\left(x\right)$ is not a piecewise function, but naturally contains the jump discontinuity shown. In this case, is it possible to separate the function into the $g\left(x\right)$ and $h\left(x\right)$ shown, and if so, how? Note that solutions may vary, given that the behavior of $g\left(x\right)$ and $h\left(x\right)$ could be anything after it reaches the end of the known interval $\left(-\infty, x_1\right]$ for $g\left(x\right)$ and $\left[x_1, \infty\right)$ for $h\left(x\right)$.

---

**EDIT 3:** One simple example of the problem is the breaking apart of absolute value functions.

$$f\left(x\right) = \left|x\right|$$
$$|x| > 0 \rightarrow |x|$$
$$\text{When broken apart, suggests the following:}$$
$$x > 0 \rightarrow x$$
$$\text{and}$$
$$-x > 0 \rightarrow -x$$
$$x < 0 \rightarrow -x$$

However, it is rare to find a function this simple to break apart.

Comment: Another thing that might help: the only cases in which this would be necessary really are functions with jump discontinuities or divergent asymptotic behavior.

Comment: Graphs and numerical experiments are the best way to develop intuition about what's going on. Once you know the answer from those explorations it's much easier to do the necessary algebra.

Comment: @EthanBolker I completely agree, and that's how calculus students are taught to solve these problems normally, but I think it would be interesting and useful to find a completely algebraic approach to the problem.